# sf::String put into std::map key doesn't work - the vaule is not saved into map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, sfml

as I wrote in the topic - I try to put sf::String into map first argument and it does not work. Here's the code:

```
void Flashcards::add(sf::String sf_string) {
std::string text = sf_string.toAnsiString();
std::pair<std::string,std::string> pairr = std::make_pair(text,"<Polish translation>");
std::cout << "Inserting: " << pairr.first << std::endl;
all_words.insert(pairr); //std::map<std::string, std::string> variable



void Flashcards::show() {
std::cout << "Flashcards:\n";
for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = all_words.begin(); it != all_words.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << "English word: " << it->first 
    << " " << "Polish word: " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

The result in console is:

```
Inserting: //a word//
Flashcards:
 Polish word: <Polish translation>
```

Instead of needed:

```
Inserting: hello
Flashcards:
English word: //a word// Polish word: <Polish translation>
```

Here are the variations I have already tried:

1) I switched the arguments so it looked like this: `std::make_pair("<Polish translation>",text);` and it works - hardcoded key and the value are both showed in the console (but I don't want hardcoding, what is obvious).

2) Note that this line: `std::cout << "Inserting: " << pairr.first << std::endl;` shows that the key value is converted into std::string correctly - calling this will show value we have just typed on the keyboard.

3) I tried to send the sf::String value directly to the std::make_pair() method, it works exactly the same as putting std::string there.

Can somebody say how to make this work?

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are providing as an argument to the `add` method obviously ends with a `\r` (carriage return) character, probably because you are reading it from a Windows text file using a Unix/Linux execution environment. If you capture the output of your program in a file and look at it with a hexdumper (such as `hd`), you should immediately see what is going on.

It certainly has nothing to do with your use of the C++ standard library. However, you don't need to go to all that work to insert an entry into a `std::map`. Just do this:

```
all_words[key] = value;
```

As long as `key` has the right type (or there is an automatic conversion), that will do precisely what you want in a single line easily-understood line, and probably more efficiently as well.

Comment: You were right, while getting data, I was saving 'enter' to the string by the mistake too. After some changes in the loop everything works perfectly. And thanks for the tip to shorten the code, it looks much more simple and cleaner!